# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id') after set state and try to use its value

Tags: reactjs

I have a very simple component:

```
import {InputText} from 'primereact/inputtext'

const Show = ({id}) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    itemService
      .getItem(id)
      .then((data) => {
        setItem(data)
        console.log(data)
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <InputText id='firstname' type='text' value={item.id} />
  )
}
```

When I start server I get the error:

> Server Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

When I remove `value={item.id}` from return part, the error is fixed and it shows that `itemService` successfully executed and `console.log(data)` return desired value as:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "createdAt": "2023-05-15T16:44:30.808+00:00",
  "enabled": true
}
```

Although I set the `item` **state** inside `useEffect` hook, why I get `null` value for `item`? **and how can I fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial value is `null`:

```
const [item, setItem] = useState(null)
```

That value may indeed change *at some later time*.  But on the first render of the component that value is explicitly defined as `null`.

Then you try to read a property from that value:

```
return (
  <InputText id='firstname' type='text' value={item.id} />
)
```

As the error states, you can't read `id` on `null`.  You can use optional chaining:

```
return (
  <InputText id='firstname' type='text' value={item?.id} />
)
```

Or perhaps not render at all until there's a value:

```
return (
  item === null ? null : <InputText id='firstname' type='text' value={item.id} />
)
```

Or, taking a different approach entirely, you can initialize to something other than `null`:

```
const [item, setItem] = useState({})
```

There are a variety of approaches, whatever fits your needs is fine.  The only approach that *isn't* fine is trying to de-reference a property on `null`.